# base class reference to derived object - strategy pattern

Tags: c++

Below is a simple strategy pattern implemented using the base class references to a derived object. The solution does not produce an expected result (12 and 2). When base class reference is switched to pointers, it works. Can someone explain what is happening behind the scenes with references here? The issue is in the setStrategy() method of the Context class. I am wondering why doesn't the strategy variable reference the ConcreteStrategy2 after the call to setStrategy() method?

```
#include <iostream>


class Strategy {
public:
    virtual ~Strategy() = default;

    virtual int execute(int x, int y) const = 0;
};


class ConcreteStrategy1 : public Strategy {
public:
    int execute(int x, int y) const override
    {
        return x + y;
    }
};


class ConcreteStrategy2 : public Strategy {
public:
    int execute(int x, int y) const override
    {
        return x - y;
    }
};


class Context {
    Strategy &strategy;

public:
    Context(Strategy &strategy) : strategy {strategy}
    {
    }

    void setStrategy(Strategy &strat)
    {
        this->strategy = strat;
    }

    void doLogic() const
    {
        std::cout << strategy.execute(7, 5) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ConcreteStrategy1 strat;
    Context context {strat};
    context.doLogic();

    ConcreteStrategy2 strat2;
    context.setStrategy(strat2);
    context.doLogic();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: References cannot be assigned. `this->strategy = strat;` assigns the contents of `strat` to `this->strategy` but doesn't change the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reassign a reference, but references cannot be reassigned. It assigns to `Strategy` object being referred to instead. If you make `Strategy` non-copyable/assignable that re-assignment through reference will fail to compile.

Use a pointer instead:

```
class Context {
    Strategy* strategy;
public:
    Context(Strategy &strategy) : strategy {&strategy} {}
    void setStrategy(Strategy &strat) { this->strategy = &strat; }
    void doLogic() const { std::cout << strategy->execute(7, 5) << std::endl; }
};
```

---

Using reference members is almost always a mistake because it breaks value semantics, as you observe. One can get away with using reference members in non-copyable classes.

Comment: Could you please explain what happens at the assignment? Shouldn't default assignment operator copy the vtable as well, which would effectively print what OP wants (as long as they don't want to use `strat1` anymore)?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen vtables are an implementation detail and not mandated by the standard so the assignment operator cannot require the vtable to be copied. Also note that object slicing is happening at the assignment. You can shoot yourself in the foot even more if the compiler would slice the object but still copy the vtable.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen take [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3nWdcW) example. What would happen if the vtable was copied here?

Comment: @Timo Thanks for explanation and example, I see it now. After the edit period I had the thought that copying vtable like that would put `strat1` in a weird state where it has vtable from another class, which doesn't make sense, but I forgot about slicing altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Additional solution to Maxim Egorushkins answer.

You could also use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) instead of a pointer:

```
class Context {
    std::reference_wrapper<Strategy> strategy;

public:
    Context(Strategy &strategy) : strategy {strategy} { }
    void setStrategy(Strategy &strat) { this->strategy = strat; }
    void doLogic() const { std::cout << strategy.get().execute(7, 5) << std::endl; }
};
```

Here are both versions next to each other:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dveK9T

Comment: `reference_wrapper` is just a pointer in disguise, no magic here. It should have been called `pointer_wrapper`.

Comment: Only advantage would be that `std::reference_wrapper` must be initialized with a reference and can only be assigned references. So it's basically an `non-null-pointer-wrapper`.